# Mouse pointer doesn't change shape depending on hovered elements

Tags: 20.04, xorg, firefox, google-chrome, mouse-pointer

### Summary

For a few days now my mouse pointer does not change it's shape in Chrome, Firefox or PhpStorm anymore. For example when I hover a link it won't turn into a pointer. In Thunderbird it works just fine.

### Setup

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Kernel 5.8.0-59-generic
- x11
- Chrome 91.0.4472.114
- Firefox 89.0.2

### Details

It seems to affect all mouse pointer shapes (pointer, cursor, etc.) in Chrome, Firefox and PhpStorm. When I hover a link or even text it seems the mouse pointer jumps a little to the side as if it would change but it actually does not. It makes it very hard to select text or resize elements. Interesting enough is that on any website it does not work while in the dev tools it actually does.

While writing this question I took a screenshot to demonstrate how it does not change but on the screenshot (made with ksnip) it actually shows correctly!
[image: Mouse pointer example]

I noticed the behavior starting a few days ago. I cannot exactly say if it was after upgrading packages but I did an upgrade. As far as I can tell the upgraded packages shouldn't affect the cursor. Here is the apt history:

```
Start-Date: 2021-07-05  09:00:22
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: dga (1000)
Upgrade:
php7.3-xml:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
bluez:amd64 (5.53-0ubuntu3.2, 5.53-0ubuntu3.3)
php7.4-gd:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-cli:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-xmlrpc:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-zip:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-common:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-cli:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-fpm:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-bcmath:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-mbstring:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-readline:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
bluez-cups:amd64 (5.53-0ubuntu3.2, 5.53-0ubuntu3.3)
php7.2-fpm:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.3, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04)
php7.4-sybase:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-json:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
apt:amd64 (2.0.5, 2.0.6)
php7.2-mysql:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php8.0-bz2:amd64 (8.0.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-curl:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-json:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-ldap:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-mysql:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
linux-base:amd64 (4.5ubuntu3.1, 4.5ubuntu3.5)
libpython3.8:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.3, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04)
python3.8:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.3, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04)
php7.0-common:amd64 (7.0.33-51+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.0.33-52+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-gd:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-curl:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-json:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-ldap:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-opcache:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-intl:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-sybase:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-odbc:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
apache2-data:amd64 (2.4.48-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 2.4.48-1.0+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 (2.0.5, 2.0.6)
php7.2-curl:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-xmlrpc:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-ldap:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-common:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-intl:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-opcache:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-soap:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-odbc:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-xml:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-bcmath:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-opcache:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-xml:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-zip:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-intl:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php5.6-common:amd64 (5.6.40-51+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 5.6.40-52+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-cli:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-zip:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-soap:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-odbc:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
python3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.3, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04)
firefox-locale-en:amd64 (89.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 89.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
php7.4-mysql:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-mbstring:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-readline:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-gd:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.3-fpm:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-mbstring:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.4-readline:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-xmlrpc:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.2-soap:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php7.1-common:amd64 (7.1.33-38+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.1.33-39+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
apt-utils:amd64 (2.0.5, 2.0.6)
bluez-obexd:amd64 (5.53-0ubuntu3.2, 5.53-0ubuntu3.3)
php7.3-sybase:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.5-1~20.04.3, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04)
apache2-bin:amd64 (2.4.48-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 2.4.48-1.0+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
firefox:amd64 (89.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 89.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
php7.4-common:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php8.0-common:amd64 (8.0.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
apt-transport-https:amd64 (2.0.5, 2.0.6)
php7.1-mcrypt:amd64 (7.1.33-38+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.1.33-39+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
linux-firmware:amd64 (1.187.14, 1.187.15)
php7.4-bcmath:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
libbluetooth3:amd64 (5.53-0ubuntu3.2, 5.53-0ubuntu3.3)
apache2:amd64 (2.4.48-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 2.4.48-1.0+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
apache2-utils:amd64 (2.4.48-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 2.4.48-1.0+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
libapache2-mod-php7.2:amd64 (7.2.34-22+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.2.34-23+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
libapache2-mod-php7.3:amd64 (7.3.28-2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.3.29-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
libapache2-mod-php7.4:amd64 (7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 7.4.21-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
php8.0-mysql:amd64 (8.0.7-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.0.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
End-Date: 2021-07-05  09:05:13

Start-Date: 2021-07-08  08:37:11
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: dga (1000)
Install:
libgoocanvas-2.0-9:amd64 (2.0.4-1, automatic)
libnumber-bytes-human-perl:amd64 (0.11-1, automatic)
libgoocanvas2-cairotypes-perl:amd64 (0.001-1~ppa~focal0, automatic)
libgoocanvas2-perl:amd64 (0.06-1, automatic)
libcarp-always-perl:amd64 (0.16-1, automatic)
libreadonly-perl:amd64 (2.050-2, automatic)
libgoocanvas-2.0-common:amd64 (2.0.4-1, automatic)
libgtk3-imageview-perl:amd64 (9-1~ppa~focal4, automatic)
gir1.2-goocanvas-2.0:amd64 (2.0.4-1, automatic)
Upgrade:
libavahi-glib1:amd64 (0.7-4ubuntu7, 0.7-4ubuntu7.1)
libavahi-common-data:amd64 (0.7-4ubuntu7, 0.7-4ubuntu7.1)
libavahi-common3:amd64 (0.7-4ubuntu7, 0.7-4ubuntu7.1)
linux-base:amd64 (4.5ubuntu3.5, 4.5ubuntu3.6)
libgupnp-1.2-0:amd64 (1.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1.2.4-0ubuntu1)
shutter:amd64 (0.94.3-1~0linuxuprising1~focal1, 0.97-1~0linuxuprising1~focal1)
libavahi-ui-gtk3-0:amd64 (0.7-4ubuntu7, 0.7-4ubuntu7.1)
libuv1:amd64 (1.34.2-1ubuntu1.1, 1.34.2-1ubuntu1.3)
avahi-daemon:amd64 (0.7-4ubuntu7, 0.7-4ubuntu7.1)
libavahi-core7:amd64 (0.7-4ubuntu7, 0.7-4ubuntu7.1)
avahi-autoipd:amd64 (0.7-4ubuntu7, 0.7-4ubuntu7.1)
avahi-utils:amd64 (0.7-4ubuntu7, 0.7-4ubuntu7.1)
libavahi-client3:amd64 (0.7-4ubuntu7, 0.7-4ubuntu7.1)
End-Date: 2021-07-08  08:37:18
```

The upgrade today did not change anything.

There is a [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/1168157/872115) for 19.04 on wayland and I am not sure if they are related.

I am using a docking station (USB-C Triple-4K Dock from Displaylink) and I think it might have to do with the driver because it actually only affects the two screens that are connected via display port. When I move Chrome to my third screen it is displayed just fine.

**How can I fix this mouse-pointer misbehavior or at least narrow it down to a cause?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was solely related to the docking station. Reattaching the display port wires did not help but restarting the whole docking station did.